# Error mounting Arch Linux NFS share on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows, linux, nfs

I'm trying to mount an NFS share over a LAN:

- Server: Arch Linux x64
- Client: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

The server already successfully exports NFS shares to other Linux machines, so I'm pretty sure it has no problems. I added an entry in `/etc/exports` for the new Windows machine and restarted the `nfs-server` service.

On the Windows machine, I enabled the following in "Add/Remove Programs":

- Services for NFS
- Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications

Then, following the guide [here](http://sagehacks.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/howto-mount-nfs-shares-under-windows-7/) I tried to run the following command to mount the NFS share so it would show up as the `Z:\` drive:

```
mount //192.168.1.99/data/authorized Z:
```

I got the following output:

```
cmdlet New-PSDrive at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Root:
```

It was waiting for me to enter something for "Root:". I'm guessing this means the NFS share root, so I entered it (`/data/authorized`), although it should've already been picked up from my initial command.

That's when I got this error:

```
New-PSDrive : Cannot find a provider with the name 'Z:'.
At line:1 char:6
+ mount <<<<  //192.168.1.99/ Z:
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (z:String) [New-PSDrive], ProviderNotFou
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriv
```

How do I get the share to mount successfully?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `mount` you are running is the wrong one.

You are attempting to use `mount` in PowerShell, whereas the article is referring to the `mount` utility that is available from the regular Windows command-line interface (`cmd`), once you've added the NFS services/features to Windows 7 (`Control Panel->Programs->Turn Windows features on or off->Services for NFS`).

For comparison...

PowerShell `Mount`:

[image: Mount in PS]

CMD `Mount`:

[image: NFS Mount in CMD]

Comment: That was the problem. The final command I had to use was `mount -o anon \\192.168.1.99\data\authorized Z:`. The `-o anon` option was required, and only backslashes could be used for directory separation.